# How to read a file in SML line by line

Tags: sml, smlnj

I want to write a function that reads a text file line by line. ie, read the first line until EOL and then treat this as a string, and repeat this until the text ends.
I have managed only this much till now:

```
fun read file = 
let val is = TextIO.openIn file
in
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TextIO.inputLine : instream -> string option` for this. Using `ref`s you can do something like

```ml
let
  val stream = TextIO.openIn file
  val done = ref false
in
  while not (!done) do
    case TextIO.inputLine stream of
      SOME s => print s
    | NONE => done := true
end
```

You can also use the functions in `TextIO.StreamIO`.